# Unable to return value to DataGridView in the other form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview called `logDataGridView` in my `AnalyzerForm` project.
In order to access to it's `DataSource` property from the other from, called `Form2`, in the project, below access field has been defined into the `AnalyzerForm.Designer.cs`:

```
Public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView _DGV
{
    get {return this.logDataGridView;}
    set {logDataGridView.DataSource = value;}
}
```

And finally, i try to use a filled `DataTable` called `t` from the `Form2`:

```
AnalyzerForm AZ = new AnalyzerForm();
AZ._DGV.DataSource = t;
```

Nothing will be shown into the `logDataGridView`!!!
Does anybody have any idea about the wrong part?

Comment: You return DataGridView in the get part, and set the DataSource in the set part. This is probably not a good idea. Anyway, have you tried to make a Refresh after set the DataSource?

Comment: @Biri: As a matter of fact, the `Refresh` did nothing...

Comment: Maybe setting the datasource to null and then to the real value? Btw, what is the datasource? What type of object?

Comment: Also, can you check what is the datasource after the set?

Comment: @Biri: `DataSource` is a `DataTable` object, is which filled in a right manner... But even null setting and its reset didn't do something special!

Comment: I've completed a sample project, it is working for me, even without refresh: http://workaholic_hu/temp/StackOverflow/matinking.zip
Maybe a little bit more code from the project would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the wrong part of the progress is just reinstantiation of the parent form, as below:

```
AnalyzerForm AZ = new AnalyzerForm();
```

One must use the very parent form reference, is which responsible for launching the child form. It is possible to define a secondary constructor for the child parent and feed a parent form object just inside of it:

```
ParentForm pForm;

public childForm(ParentForm FRM)
{
    pForm = FRM;
    // Then component initializing...
}
```

Finally, the required component of the parent form (is which a datagridview, in my case), is possible:

```
pForm._DVG.DataSource = t;
```

Comment: I thought it was out of the question, because when you say new xy(), you get a new object, which mostly has nothing to do with the any other, previoyusly created object.

Comment: @Biri: That was the case, actually. As a matter of fact, existence of the first `parentForm` object was obvious, but the approach to handle it is something like above... Thank you for your contribution.